# Statistical significant of average time series shapes

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Let's say we have a number of time series that come from different observations of related events. For example, 10 similar events centred around the end of a quarter describing measures taken the 100 days before and 100 days after the the end of the quarter.

[image]

The average of those time series can form a distinctive upside down V shape (or any other shape). 
[image]

Averaging the time series is decent way to find patterns but we want to also visualise (or quantify) the statistical significance of these shapes. When does the shape start and end? How strong is it between -50 and 50 or between -100 and 100?

The statistical significance should increase with the number of observations that *agree* with a shape along different parts of the time series.

We can see an average upside down V shape with this extreme example. It has no statical significance because the variance is large and there is a small number of observations.
[image]

[image]

What is good statical tool to visualise that? Is there some kind of confidence interval technique around the averages of time-series?

Comment: Can you please tell us what these series represent, and what is the ultimate goal ?